# Applications are launched sequentially from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command, windows-server-2008-r2

I have following command file on a Windows Server 2008 R2. It is for running multiple copies of same `exe` (from different folders).  However the applications are launched sequentially – second one launches only after the first one.  I need to all of them together (without waiting for the completion of previous one). How can we modify the script to make it working like that?

Note: The second command line parameter is  for closing the application after a specified time (in milliseconds).

*Command File*

```
echo off

D:

CD "\B2B\program\B2BCrawler\Contract1\Athletics\"

B2B_Crawler_V2.exe HeaderMenu_DropDown_6 1800 50


D:

CD "\B2B\program\B2BCrawler\Contract1\Brands\"

B2B_Crawler_V2.exe HeaderMenu_DropDown_5 18000000 50


D:

CD "\B2B\program\B2BCrawler\Contract1\Featured\"

B2B_Crawler_V2.exe HeaderMenu_DropDown_4 18000000 50



D:

CD "\B2B\program\B2BCrawler\Contract1\Men\"

B2B_Crawler_V2.exe HeaderMenu_DropDown_1 18000000 50



D:

CD "\B2B\program\B2BCrawler\Contract1\Women\"

B2B_Crawler_V2.exe HeaderMenu_DropDown_2 18000000 50



D:

CD "\B2B\program\B2BCrawler\Contract1\Youth\"

B2B_Crawler_V2.exe HeaderMenu_DropDown_3 18000000 50



exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
B2B_Crawler_V2.exe ...
```

to

```
start "Windowtitle" B2B_Crawler_V2.exe ...
```

where windowtitle is the title of the window created (duh) and can be empty if you wish (but retain the double-quotes)